# Find indices of slope changes in a vector in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with two columns: (1) datetimes and (2) streamflow values. I would like to create a 3rd column with indicator values to find sudden increases (usually a 0 but it is a 1 when the streamflow shows a big increase).

```
datetime <-  as.POSIXct(c(1557439200, 1557440100, 1557441000, 1557441900,1557442800, 
          1557443700, 1557444600, 1557445500, 1557446400, 1557447300, 1557448200, 1557449100, 1557450000, 1557450900, 
          1557451800, 1557452700, 1557453600, 1557454500, 1557455400, 1557456300, 1557457200, 1557458100, 1557459000), origin = "1970-01-01")enter code here
streamflow <-  c(0.35, 0.35, 0.36,  0.54, 1.0, 2.7, 8.4, 9.3, 6.2, 3.8, 4.7, 
             2.91, 2.01, 1.65, 1.41, 1.12, 0.95, 0.62, 0.52, 0.53, 0.53, 0.44, 0.35) 

data <- data.table(as.POSIXct(datetime), as.numeric(streamflow))
```

I am trying to create a function that would identify the datetime of where it jumps from 0.5 to 1 because that is when the event starts. It would then stop indicating it is an event when the streamflow goes below a certain threshold.

My current idea is a function that compares the local slope between two consecutive points in streamflow to a slope of all the values of streamflow within some window, but I don't really know how to write that. Or maybe there is a better idea for how to do what I am trying to do

Comment: Are you asking for where the _value_ of streamflow is >0.5 or where the change in streamflow is greater than 0.5?

Comment: Are you looking for something like: `match(TRUE, c(FALSE, diff(data[,2]) >= 1))` ?

Comment: I am asking for something to identify large jumps in the streamflow values. There is a very long time series and this is just some example data, the jump will not always be from 0.5 to 1. I think the best way would be to find where the slope over a moving window changes.

Comment: Hi @BeckyF - I think the problem is a bit vague ... what do you mean by "sudden" increases or "big" increase - how big (in absolute terms or relative to some reference data or...)?

Comment: @ValeriVoev, Thanks for the question. I have a whole year of data with over 130  events where the streamflow data increases. The problem is that across all this data the actual value of the increases varies:  it could be 0.3 --> 0.9, or 0.5 --> 4, or even 0.6 --> 8 from one measurement to the next.  The reference data will the data before it. To quantify "big" for this example, let say that if a datapoint is 50% larger than the datapoint before it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
data = data[, delta := (V2-lag(V2))/lag(V2)][
  , ind_jump := delta > 0.5
]

indices <- data[ind_jump==TRUE, V1]
```

Not related to this, but for some weird reason R gives

```r
(0.54 - 0.36)/0.36 > 0.5
[1] TRUE
```

while

```r
0.18/0.36 > 0.5
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Just to close this one off ... decimal number math is in general (not only in R) not precise. See, e.g., https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f